# How do I enforce set-like uniqueness between multiple columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint

I'm not sure I've phrased the question correctly, so I'll try a longer explanation. I have this kind of table:

```
CREATE TABLE x (a int, b int);
```

I want to consider the pair (a,b) to be identical to (b,a), and to disallow insertion of duplicates. If PostgreSQL had a `set` data type, I might declare the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
    ab set,
    UNIQUE (ab)
);
```

But it doesn't, so what's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create unique index idx_unique_ab 
    on x (least(a,b), greatest(a,b));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just enforce that a pair can only be stored one way round then create a regular unique constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE x
  (
     a INT,
     b INT,
     CHECK (a < b),
     UNIQUE(a, b)
  );
```

Comment: Unfortunately this would prevent initial insertion of the pair (2,1), which is not against the rules.

Comment: @ji6 - The rules indicate that `(2,1)` is semantically equivalent to `(1,2)` and the choice is either to sort this out at insert time so that the inserts ensure that a consistent format is used (could use triggers) or store a redundant copy of the data in this format as per the other answer.